# Raspbian - Build Firefox from sources

Tags: firefox, debian, build

I've tried building Firefox from sources on my raspberry pi using the following commands but starting firefox produces this error: `-bash: /usr/bin/firefox: can't execute this file.` (translated manually). How can I fix this problem?

```
sudo apt-src install firefox
sudo apt-src build firefox
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: Can you post output of the following command: `file /usr/bin/firefox`?

Comment: `/usr/bin/firefox: symbolic link to \`/opt/firefox/firefox'`

Comment: Good. Now can you post output of `file /opt/firefox/firefox`?

Comment: `/opt/firefox/firefox: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=0x6e884103555b3e2bc8ecc62624d2d8123d61980e, stripped
`

Comment: Your Firefox is compiled for i386 architecture (`Intel 80386`). Raspberry PI has ARM processor - it is different architecture, thus you are getting error `can't execute this file`. ARM processor can not run binary compiled for i386 arch. Not sure how `apt-src` works and what it does but looks like you did not compile Firefox, but sort of extracted pre-compiled version. I guess on Raspberry PI it will take really long time to compile Firefox. How long did you wait for it to compile?

Answer (score 1):

On the Raspberry Pi and Debian you need to install Iceweasel.  It is Mozilla's browser for that distribution.  Run: 'sudo apt-get install iceweasel' and you should be able to install without any changed repositories.  See the link below:

http://elinux.org/RPi_IceWeasel

If you are absolutely bent on getting full-fledged Firefox on the RPi, here is a link that may be helpful.  There is a lot of extra work as opposed to using Iceweasel:

http://featherweightmusings.blogspot.com/2013/03/firefox-on-raspberry-pi.html